# c# xna programming spritebatch error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
       SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D myTexture;
        Rectangle myRectangle;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()

        {


            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            //spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Texture myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");

            myRectangle = new Rectangle(10, 100, 30, 50);
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture,myRectangle,Color.White);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

NullReferenceExcerption was unhandled
in this code the debugging will start but it will get an error message like this

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
which points on `spriteBatch.begin()`
and it contains so many links etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this line commented out, which is causing your spriteBatch to never be initialized.

```
//spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
```

Comment: new error!!!!! This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture   on the  `
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture,myRectangle,Color.White);`

Comment: That's because you're loading myTexture into a separate variable which is locally scoped to the LoadContent method, change it to `myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character");`